# Is there a PowerShell script that displays the files within the directory and deletes the .xml files within those folders

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm trying to display the .xml files and then delete them all. All other files for example, .txt, .pdf files can stay in the folder. Here is what I have so far. I'm pretty new to scripting and trying to find the efficient way since I have multiple folders.

```
$Folders = Get-childitem "my path" -Name
$HR = $Folders
$HR
foreach ($item in $HR)
{
    $path = "my path" +$item + "\config\"
    $path
    $file = Get-ChildItem $path
    $file
        foreach ($item2 in $file) {

          if ($file.name -eq 'XML*') {
             $file
          }
    Get-ChildItem -include *
  }
}
```

I do get the files displayed from each directory but I could not somehow exclude the .txt, .pdf files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as a one liner:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq ".xml"} | ForEach-Object { del $_.FullName}
```

Just call this from which ever directory you want to delete all xml files from.

Or if its a hierarchy of directories like

E:\AppFiles
      .\TempFiles
      .\Images

You can ise the -recurse switch too.